# Transforming a data frame and calculate the mean by group

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID  A  V
1   M  4
1   D  6
1   M  10
2   D  3
2   D  7
```

Which I want to transform into this:

```
ID M D V
1  7 6 10
2    5 5
```

Basically, I want to calculate the mean by group. I have used "aggregate" and "plyr" package but no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You really should elaborate a bit more on your expected output.

Comment: What's the "V" column in the result?

Comment: is the mean of the ID. but the value should be 6.666667 instead of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the operation you want to perform actually requires several steps:

**1:** Group by both `ID` and `A` and calculate the means of `V`.

**2:** Take the result of step 1 and reshape it from long to wide format, such that each group from the original column `A` has its own column in the resulting data.frame.

**3:** Separately, group by just `ID` and calculate the means of `V`.

**4:** Merge on `ID` the results of steps 2 and 3 into a single data.frame.

This can be done with a couple of calls to [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html), a call to [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html) on the first aggregation result, and finally a call to [`merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1L,1L,1L,2L,2L),A=c('M','D','M','D','D'),V=c(4L,6L,10L,3L,7L),stringsAsFactors=F);
merge(reshape(aggregate(V~ID+A,df,mean),dir='w',idvar='ID',timevar='A'),aggregate(V~ID,df,mean));
##   ID V.D V.M        V
## 1  1   6   7 6.666667
## 2  2   5  NA 5.000000
```

(I think you made a mistake when typing out your expected output; the mean of `V` for group `ID=1` is 6.666667, not 10.)

Comment: Thank you, you read my mind :)